# How have I done a redirect on yii

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, yii, url-rewriting

I have an url.

```
http://www.example.org/index.php/
http://www.example.org/index.php
http://www.example.org/
http://www.example.org
http://example.org/index.php/
http://example.org/index.php
```

I need rewrite to

```
http://example.org/
```

to work including a css style and a js on yii.
now I use this .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

and I found this solve

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yoursite.org(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yoursite.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

how can this combine?
how do I put "/" a slash in (all) end of path or delete the slash?

Comment: add the rules in the 1st snippet after the rules in the 2nd snippet, htaccess rules i.e.

Comment: This webpage has a redirect loop or Moved Permanently